# Eliminate duplicate records/rows?

Tags: sql, database, oracle11g

I'm trying to list result from a multi-table query with on row, 2 columns. I have the correct data that I need, I merely need to trim it down to 1 line of results. In other words, eliminate duplicate entries in the result. I'm using a value not shown here, school_id. Should I go with that as a distinct value? Can I do that without displaying the school_id?

```
SQL> select DISTINCT(school_name),Team_Name
  2  from school, team
  3  where team.team_name like '%B%'
  4  AND school.school_id = team.school_id;

SCHOOL_NAME                                        TEAM_NAME
-------------------------------------------------- ----------
Lawrence Central High School                       Bears
Lawrence Central High School                       BEars
Lawrence Central High School                       BEARS
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem, as I'm sure you know, is the fact that "Bears" is in 3 different cases here.  The simple fix is to do the upper or lower of "Team_Name" so it will only have 1 return record.

```
UPPER(Team_Name)
```